# Moving a continuously rotating imageview android using onTouch MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview

I am trying to move a continuously rotating imageview using onTouch event but after repoistioning imageview. it dose not rotate around its own axis instead rotates around a long circular path.

What I want is something like image below:

[CLICK HERE FOR IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWnzk.png)

What I am getting after repositioning using onTouch event is this:

[CLICK HERE FOR IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeUXb.png)

So far I am able to roatate image around its own axis using this code:

```
RotateAnimation rotateanimation = new RotateAnimation(0, 360,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
```

I think its something to got do with pivotPoints which I cant figure out. Below is the code.

```
    final ImageView iv = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    final RotateAnimation rotateAnimation;


    RotateAnimation rotateanimation = new RotateAnimation(0, 360,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

    rotateanimation.setDuration(7000);
    rotateanimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    rotateanimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    rotateanimation.setFillAfter(true);
    iv.startAnimation(rotateanimation);


        iv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        PointF DownPT = new PointF(); // Record Mouse Position When Pressed Down
        PointF StartPT = new PointF(); // Record Start Position of 'img'


        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, final MotionEvent event)
        {


            switch (event.getAction())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :
                    PointF mv = new PointF( event.getX() - DownPT.x -1, event.getY() - DownPT.y -1);
                    iv.setX((int)(StartPT.x+mv.x));
                    iv.setY((int)(StartPT.y+mv.y));

                    iv.setPivotX(StartPT.x+mv.x);
                    iv.setPivotY(StartPT.y+mv.y);

                    //something to do here i guess
                     rotateanimation = new RotateAnimation(0, 360,
                            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, iv.getPivotX(),
                            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, iv.getPivotY());

                    iv.startAnimation(rotateanimation);

                    /**************************************************************/

                    StartPT = new PointF( iv.getX(), iv.getY() );
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :

                    int centerXOnImage= iv.getWidth()/2;
                    int centerYOnImage= iv.getHeight()/2;

                    DownPT.x =centerXOnImage;
                    DownPT.y =centerYOnImage;

                    StartPT = new PointF( iv.getX(), iv.getY() );
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
                    // Nothing have to do
                    break;
                default :
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 2 days of head scratching and Googling I have find out the way.

All you need to do is use event.getRawX() and event.getRawY() instead of event.getX() and event.getY(). It will keep rotating imageview under users fingers.

I changed RotateAnimation to ObjectAnimation because when user touch is involved around an playing animation standard animation will behave odd.

Here is the code:

```
ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(iv, "rotation",360f);
    anim.setDuration(7000);
    anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    anim.start();





       iv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        PointF DownPT = new PointF(); // Record Mouse Position When Pressed Down
        PointF StartPT = new PointF(); // Record Start Position of 'img'


        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, final MotionEvent event)
        {




            switch (event.getAction())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :



                    PointF mv = new PointF( event.getRawX()  , event.getRawY());


                    iv.setX((int)event.getRawX() - DownPT.x);
                    iv.setY((int)event.getRawY() - DownPT.y);

                    StartPT = new PointF( iv.getX(), iv.getY() );

                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :

                    int centerXOnImage= iv.getWidth()/2;
                    int centerYOnImage= iv.getHeight()/2;

                    DownPT.x =centerXOnImage;
                    DownPT.y =centerYOnImage;

                    StartPT = new PointF( iv.getX(), iv.getY() );


                    anim.setDuration(2000);
                    anim.start();

                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :

                   //do stuff here
                    break;
                default :
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Hope it will help someone in future :)